# Calculate full elapsed friendly time from two NSDates

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to create a method that calculates the full time in the format of:
`0 Year 0 month 1 day 1 hour 15 minutes 5 seconds`

I am passing the following two dates as examples. Which should be 1 hour 15 minutes and 5 seconds.

```
NSString * startDate = @"2016-08-24 10:00:00";
NSString * endDate   = @"2016-08-24 11:15:05";
NSLog(@"Total Time: %@", [self caluculateTimeFrom:startDate endDate:endDate]);
```

The method to do the calculations

```
- (NSString*) caluculateTimeFrom:(NSString*)startDate endDate:(NSString*)endDate {

    NSLog(@"Start Date: %@", startDate);
    NSLog(@"End Date: %@", endDate);
    if (startDate == nil || endDate == nil) {
        return nil;
    }


    NSString * returnDate = @"";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate * date1 = [dateFormater dateFromString:startDate];
    NSDate * date2 = [dateFormater dateFromString:endDate];

    float totalElapsedSeconds = roundf([date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]);
    NSLog(@"totalElapsedTime: %f", totalElapsedSeconds);

    if (totalElapsedSeconds < SECOND ) {
        returnDate = @"0 seconds";
        return returnDate;
    }

    float days = totalElapsedSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24);
    totalElapsedSeconds -= days * (60 * 60 * 24);
    float hours = totalElapsedSeconds / (60 * 60);
    totalElapsedSeconds -= hours * (60 * 60);
    float minutes = totalElapsedSeconds / 60;

    returnDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f days %f hours %f minutes", days, hours, minutes];


    return returnDate;
}
```

I have looked over SO quiestions but theyu all seem to only spit out 1 instance. ie 1 day ago but not the full string with the remainders.

What am I doing wrong? **Please no external Github frameworks or CocoaPods.** As the ones most [people recommend](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo) do not accomplish what I want.

**UPDATE User Rob suggested using** `NSDateComponentsFormatter`

To get the style I wanted here is the code for future use. This only works on iOS 8+

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull;
    formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
```

Comment: Once you have your two `NSDate` objects, use `NSDateComponentsFormatter` to build your string of the time elapsed.

Comment: That doesn't work. It spits out `About 75 minutes remaining`

Comment: @Firemarble You need to configure the `NSDateComponentsFormatter` properly to get what you want.

Comment: Update your question with the output you actually get versus what you expect to get. BTW - you have the wrong format in your date formatter. Use `yyyy` for the year, not `YYYY`.

Comment: Yes, @Rob I have already solved the issue thanks to your suggestion. I updated the question to reflect your contribution.

Comment: Excellent. I'd suggest, though, that you remove that edit and instead post an answer to your question. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think your calculation method implementation should be something like this:

```
- (NSString *)caluculateTimeFrom:(NSString*)startDate endDate:(NSString*)endDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:startDate];
    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:endDate];

    NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

    NSCalendarUnit units = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units
                                               fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [components setYear:1];
    [components setMonth:1];
    [components setDay:1];
    [components setHour:0];
    [components setMinute:0];
    [components setSecond:0];

    NSDate *zeroDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:zeroDate];

    components = [calendar components:units
                             fromDate:date];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Year %ld month %ld day %ld hour %ld minutes %ld seconds", components.year - 1,
                        components.month - 1,
                        components.day - 1,
                        components.hour,
                        components.minute,
                        components.second];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what was wrong and how your solution fixes the issue. Code-only answers are frowned upon here.